# How to not display the value

Tags: javascript, html, css, color-picker, jscolor

I am using [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) to pick a color with an input.

I wanted to style it but I can't get rid of the hex value of the color choosen and I didn't find any documentation about options.

**What I've tried :**

```
//It shows nothing
display: none 
//It works but then the dot isn't properly aligned
font-size:0 
//does nothing    
class="jscolor "{valueElement:null, value:"#e6e5f4"}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ayLhLpc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
class="jscolor "{valueElement:null, value:"#e6e5f4"}
```

to:

```
class="jscolor {valueElement:null, value:'#e6e5f4'}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but I can still see the cursor blinking, can I disable this too ?

Comment: Just use a [button](http://jscolor.com/examples/#example-button-element) instead of input.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `jscolor` class, like so:

```
<br><div id="cb">
        <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
        <input id="CLR1" class="jscolor {valueElement:null, value:'#e6e5f4'}">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
                Must stay approximately aligned
          </label>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class wasn't applied due to your typo error.

Choose one of the following corrections:

`<input id="CLR1" class="jscolor {valueElement:null, value:'#e6e5f4'}">` (preferred)

`<input id="CLR1" class='jscolor {valueElement:null, value:"#e6e5f4"}'>`

⋅
⋅
⋅

Then, to make it properly aligned, you can just remove the `top` on the `.checkbox` element:

```
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  /* top: -0.375rem; */
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ayLhLpc/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah as the others answers pointed out it was just a typo. Thank you for the bonus with the top property, although I didn't ask for it, it really helped !